# Django and models with multiple foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am new to Django and I've been impressed so far by its capabilities. I am playing with more complex models and I am have problem to use them properly. Using Django 1.3, I am trying to write a summary page which would present the three models below with the following structure. In other words, a list of trips with their destinations and activities.

- Trip 1

  - Destination 1
  - Destination 2
  - Activity 1
- Trip 2

  - Destination 1
  - Activity 2

**Models**

- Trip <-> TripDestination <-> Destination (a trip can have multiple destinations)
- Activity -> Trip, Activity -> Destination (an activity is defined for a trip at a specific location/destination)

```
    class Destination(models.Model):
        city_name=models.CharField()

    class Trip(models.Model):
        departing_on=models.DateField()
        returning_on=models.DateField()
        destinations=models.ManyToManyField(Destination)

    class Activity(models.Model):
        destination=models.ForeignKey(Destination, null=False)
        trip=models.ForeignKey(Trip, null=False)
```

I am trying to write a view which would generate a page with the structure presented above. The main problem I am having right now is to display the activities for a specific trip and destination. As you can see in the code below, I am building a dictionary and I doubt it is the right thing to do. In addition, the view becomes

**View**

```
def list_trip(request, template_name = 'trip-list.html'):
    trips = Trip.objects.all()

    # Build a dictionary for activities -- Is this the right thing to do?
    activities = Activity.objects.filter(trip__in=trips)
    activities_by_trips = dict()
    for activity in activities:
        if activity.trip_id not in activities_by_trips:
            activities_by_trips[activity.trip_id] = dict()

        if activity.destination_id not in activities_by_trips[activity.trip_id]:
            activities_by_trips[activity.trip_id][activity.destination_id] = []

        activities_by_trips[activity.trip_id][activity.destination_id].append(activity)

    return render_to_response(template_name, {
        'page_title': 'List of trips',
        'trips': trips,
        'activities_by_trips': activities_by_trips,
    })
```

**Template**

```
{% block content %}
    {% for trip in trips %}
        {{ trip.id }} - {{ trip.name }}

        {% for destination in trip.destinations.all %}
            {{ destination.city_name }}

            ** This is terrible code -- How to fix that **
            {% for key, value in activities_by_trips|dict_lookup:trip.id %}
                {% if value %}
                    {% for key_prime, value_prime in value|dict_lookup:destination.id %}
                       {{ value_prime.description }}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

In brief, can someone please help me to get a summary of all the trips and activities? What's the best way to accomplish that? Is the model correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

There is plenty of room for improvement. By using through on ManyToManyField you can explicitly define the join table, which we can conveniently consider as a single visit to a city during a particular trip. During that visit we had activities, so activity should have a foreignkey to a visit.

For each foreignkey in a table, Django will add API convenience manager for sets of objects on the opposite side of the relationship. `Destination` will have a `visit_set`, but so will `Trip`. Similarly, because of `visit` foreignkey in `Activity` each visit will have an `activity_set`.

First start with the models:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Destination(models.Model):
    city_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Trip(models.Model):
    departing_on=models.DateField()
    returning_on=models.DateField()
    destinations=models.ManyToManyField(Destination, through='Visit')

class Visit(models.Model):
    destination=models.ForeignKey(Destination)
    trip=models.ForeignKey(Trip)

class Activity(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    visit=models.ForeignKey(Visit)
```

Then lets change `list_trip` a bit, added print_trip for clarity of what is going on in template:

```
def list_trip(request, template_name = 'trip-list.html'):
    return render_to_response(template_name, {
        'page_title': 'List of trips',
        'trips': Trip.objects.all(),
        })

def print_trips():
    for trip in Trip.objects.all():
        for visit in trip.visit_set.select_related().all():
            print trip.id, '-', visit.destination.city_name
            for act in visit.activity_set.all():
                print act.name
```

And finally the improved template:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for trip in trips %}
        {{ trip.id }} - {{ trip.name }}

        {% for visit in trip.visit_set.select_related.all %}
            {{ visit.destination.city_name }}

            {% for act in visit.activity_set.all %}
                 {{ act.name }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

There is still some more room for improvement performance wise. Notice I used select_related. That will prefetch all destinations at the time visits are fetched, so that visit.destination.city_name will not incur another db call. However this doesn't work for reverse ManyToMany relationships (in our case all members of activity_set). Django 1.4 will come out with new method called prefetch_related which will resolve that as well.

In the mean time, read up on [Efficient reverse lookups](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/01/11/django-patterns-part-2-efficient-reverse-lookups/) for an idea how to even further reduce the number of DB hits. In the comments few readily available solutions are mentioned as well.

Comment: Thank you digivampire! This is exactly what I was looking for.