# django join with two foregn keys unique together

Tags: mysql, sql, django, join

I'm stuck with this. I have two table like:

```
TABLE1 (CODE,SUBCODE,DESCR,FIELD4,FIELD5,...)

TABLE2 (ID1,ID2,CODE,SUBCODE,FIELD5,FIELD6,...)
```

and the model like this:

```
class Table1(models.Model):

    code = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='CODE') # Field name made lowercase.

    subcode = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='SUBCODE') # Field name made lowercase.

    description = models.CharField(db_column='DESCR', max_length=30) # Field name made lowercase.

    field4 = models.CharField(db_column='FIELD4', max_length=8) # Field name made lowercase.

    field5 = models.CharField(db_column='FIELD5', max_length=30) # Field name made lowercase.

    (...)

class Meta:

    managed = False

    db_table = 'TABLE1'

    unique_together = (("code", "subcode"),)


class Table2(models.Model):

    id1 = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='ID1') # Field name made lowercase.

    id2 = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='ID2') # Field name made lowercase.

    code = models.IntegerField(db_column='CODE') # Field name made lowercase.<br/><br/>
    subcode = models.IntegerField(db_column='SUBCODE') # Field name made lowercase.

    field5 = models.CharField(db_column='FIELD5', max_length=32) # Field name made lowercase.

    field6 = models.FloatField(db_column='FIELD6') # Field name made lowercase.

    code_fk = models.ForeignKey(Table1, db_column='CODE', to_field='code',       related_name='code_fk')

    subcode_fk = models.ForeignKey(Table1, db_column='SUBCODE', to_field='subcode', related_name='subcode_fk')

class Meta:

    managed = False

    db_table = 'TABLE2'

    unique_together = (("id1", "id2"),)
```

If I do a simple retrieve like this:

```
Table2.objects.all()
```

There's a way to show in the template for every row returned the fields code, subcode and the relative description taken from the other table?

Substantially I want to do a simple

```
SELECT B.CODE, B.SUBCODE, A.DESCR
FROM TABLE1 A JOIN TABLE2 B
ON A.CODE = B.CODE AND A.SUBCODE = B.SUBCODE
```

How do I have to modify my model to do it?

Comment: I guess there is question similar to this. Have a look at [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449882/django-and-models-with-multiple-foreign-keys)..

Comment: Thanks! I see that, but in that case each Foreign key point to a different table. My problem is that both the foreign key together identify a single record in the other table. If I try to access to one of that, I get a MultipleObjectsReturned, and It's right, but how I can use them together to get the join working?

Comment: But if both of your foreign keys are pointing to a single entry in the other table. Why are you using two foreign keys..? Why not use a single foreign key..??

Comment: Because that table have two primary key, CODE and SUBCODE, that are both primary key, unique_together. There's a way to represent this using only one foreign key in the model? I can't change the db..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django [does not yet support multi-column primary keys](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys)... meaning only one field on your model should be marked as `primary_key=True`.

This presents a problem if you are not able to adapt your db schema to Django (which I'm guessing may be your case since you have `managed=False`)

You can try to use a module like this:
https://github.com/simone/django-compositekey
(I have not tried it personally)

Comment: Thanks! It's exactliy what I was looking for! The only problem is that I'm using django 1.6.2 and that module seems to be compatbile with the 1.4. How can I downgrade the version of django that I'm using?

Comment: @MisterFrank you can just `pip uninstall django` and then `pip install django==1.4` ...you want to be using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) so you can do this for just one project without affecting others

Comment: I found another valid alternative in using .raw() https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

Comment: @MisterFrank that will work though you lose the ability to use normal queryset methods, all your queries for that model will need to be raw